# How to check current date and system date are same?

Tags: angularjs, date, meteor, angular-material

I am using the code:

```
    <md-datepicker ng-model="reviewDate" md-placeholder="Review Date*" 
        md-min-date="currDate" md-max-date="maxDate"  
        ng-focus="createALPCtrl.errors.review_date = ''">
```

```
    $scope.currDate = new Date();
    $scope.maxDate = new Date(
    $scope.currDate.getFullYear(),
    $scope.currDate.getMonth() + 3,
    $scope.currDate.getDate());
```

It is giving correct values when the local system date is correct. But when I changing the local system date to some other date it is showing wrong date as current date.

How can I overcome this?

Comment: Define `current date`. Is it some ntp sourced time? Or your server time?

Comment: I retrieved server date from server side code and using that server date, I set the min and Max date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I retrieved server date from server side code and using that server date, I set the min and Max date.

Server Code :

```
Meteor.methods({
  currentDate: function() {
    let currDate = new Date();
    return currDate
  }
})
```

Client Code :

```
Meteor.call('currentDate', function(error, result) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log(result);
    $scope.currDate = result;
  }
});
```

It is working fine.